# Error while connecting with Visual SVN Server using Cornerstone

Tags: macos, svn, visualsvn-server, cornerstone

I am trying to connect with the SVN server using Cornerstone in Mac. Here is the URL of our server.

[image]

Now, I am getting below error message.
[image]

Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you should enter to client looks likes this:

`https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo/foo/bar`

This issue is completely unrelated to the Subversion client you use.

[The URL you see in address bar of a web browser is specific to the new HTML5-based web interface of VisualSVN Server](http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/), it has special format and arguments that Subversion clients do not understand. In other words, the URL you see in web browser's address (URL) bar can't be passed to Subversion client as is. To get the URL to pass to a client, you can click on a "Checkout" button at the top right corner of the web interface (third from the right).

Comment: I just missed out that one. Thank you.